# Why is this utilized variable grayed out?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, global-variables, resharper, unused-variables

I have two local vars with the same raison d'etre, _lastShortName and _lastCompanyName :

```
private string _lastShortName = String.Empty;
private string _lastCompanyName = String.Empty;

    ...which are used like this:

    private void AddFillRateByDCByLocationRow(FillRateByDCByLocation 
frbdcbl)
    {
        int rowToPopulate = 
_xlSheetFillRateByDCByLocation.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1;

        // Don't want repeats of ShortName
        if (!_lastShortName.Equals(frbdcbl.ShortName))
        {
            var shortNameCell = 
(Excel.Range)_xlSheetFillRateByDCByLocation.Cells[rowToPopulate,
SHORTNAME_BYDCBYLOC_COL];
            shortNameCell.Value2 = frbdcbl.ShortName;
            shortNameCell.Font.Bold = true;
        }
        _lastShortName = frbdcbl.ShortName;

        // ... or CompanyName
        if (!_lastCompanyName.Equals(frbdcbl.CompanyName))
        {
            var companyNameCell = 
(Excel.Range)_xlSheetFillRateByDCByLocation.Cells[rowToPopulate, 
COMPANYNAME_BYDCBYLOC_COL];
            companyNameCell.Value2 = frbdcbl.CompanyName;
            companyNameCell.Font.Bold = true;
        }
        _lastCompanyName = frbdcbl.CompanyName;
        . . .
```

Yet _lastCompanyName is grayed out where it is declared. Why would that be? Resharper > Inspect > Code Issues in Solution does not say it is an unused variable, so it must be Visual Studio that is doing the graying, but why?

Comment: restart visual studio and see if it persists

Comment: I'll be darned like a holey sock - that did it. Odd/interesting that it would gray out the one variable but not the other; but who knows what evil lurks in the innards of compilers?

Comment: I have the same issue and restarting VS does not help